# spring boot config server properties files under different folders?

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot

Does anybody knows if we can store the properties file under different folders on github and then spring-boot config server can read those files?

for example if my repository for properties file is:

- https://github.com/chetankokil/configfiles

Can i have as many folder as i want under config-files repository and then these folders will have properties files under it? Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at [Spring Could Config](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config) module. Spring ecosystem has your use case covered and it's better to follow proven footsteps rather than creating your custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create various directories in Github and provide bootstrap.properties file in your project.  A sample bootstrap file is shown below

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=<your config server url>
spring.application.name=<your folder name in github>
spring.cloud.config.label=<github project branch name>
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
spring.profiles.active=<active profile in spring>
```