# Is it necessary to name property file in Github on the name of spring application name of client

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have one spring cloud config server which is pointing to a github url to access properties file.
The client is pointed to cloud config server for dynamic change in properties file.
Is it necessary that the file present in the github repository should have the same name as the spring application.

Answer (score 1):

By default the client will use its `spring.application.name` when looking for a config file from the server but you [can override the name that the client uses by setting a `spring.cloud.config.name`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#_locating_remote_configuration_resources) in its bootstrap file.

(You can try it in [this demo project](https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/configserverexample) by changing the name of the configclient.properties file to something else and setting `spring.cloud.config.name` to the new name in the client's bootstrap.properties and then running through the steps in the [README](https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/configserverexample/blob/master/README.md).)

Comment: but i cant use more than 2 properties for a single client.

Comment: Yes you can do that too. You can use the `spring.application.name` as the directory name (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271599/9705485) and the client will scan the files that the server hosts under that directory. So you could match multiple, say if your client is using @ConfigurationProperties. You can also do that in the referenced demo project by moving the configclient.properties to a new subdirectory called `configclient` and renaming it to `application.properites`.

Comment: you can also have a comma separated list in spring.cloud.config.name.